# Effects on motor encoder by over-volting

Tags: dc-motor, encoder

I'm using Maxon RE-max 17 4.5W 12V DC motor with encoder attached for my research. Currently I'm using up to 18V for the voltage input to get a better rotation speed and torque.

My questions: **Is this likely to affect the lifespan of the encoder/motor? If not, why?**

Thanks in advance.

p/s: For reference, [this motor](http://www.maxonmotor.com/maxon/view/product/motor/dcmotor/remax/remax17/216010) and [this encoder](http://www.maxonmotor.com/maxon/view/product/sensor/encoder/Encoder-MR-TypM-128-512imp-2-3Kanal/201940) is the closest versions currently available.

Comment: You don't give any information about the encoder you are using. If for instance it is this one http://www.maxonmotor.com/medias/sys_master/root/8816812654622/15-346-EN.pdf which has a Vcc of 5V +/- 10%; 18v would be bad.

Comment: @Tyler I'm using 5V for the encoder but 18V for the motor. I've also updated the reference for both motor and encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the motor voltage from 12 to 18 volts will increase the speed proportionally from 7650 RPM to 11475 RPM. Note that 12 volts is listed as the nominal voltage and 11900 is the maximum speed. That would indicate that 18 volts is probably acceptable for the motor. The maximum speed of the encoder is listed as 37500 RPM, so that should be ok also. The lifetime of the motor brushes and bearings and the encoder bearings will be longer at the lower speed, but the lifetime at the higher speed is apparently estimated to be acceptable by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Under light loading it's probably OK. Under heavy torque loads you can greatly increase the brush temperatures. Also, if you can physically see the brushes, check for excessive sparking at the higher speed, which may occur at light load but will worsen at heavy load.

Carbon (graphite) brushes can tolerate this abuse better than precious metal brushes. Worth knowing because some motor sizes allow you to specify either type. I have seen metal brushes re-distribute themselves across the commutator gaps until two commutator segments shorted out. (After a new motor driver, and dismantling and digging out the detritus with a pin, that CD player is still running!)

In short, there may be some shortening of the life of the motor, so while I wouldn't do this for safety critical or high-reliability applications, it should be OK for light loads or with carbon brushes, especially if the design allows motor replacement.